# ggplot how to set y-position with geom_signif when the y-axis is logarithmic

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm not able to correctly place the labels for this plot. By 'correctly' I mean not stuck or overlapping at the top but moved down the y-axis to an appropriate position. Please see reproducible example and plots below. The current method of labelling means the y-axis position is ignored. How can I workaround this?

```
library(magrittr) 
library(dplyr) 
library(ggpubr)

set.seed(20)
col1<-c(rep('E', each = 8))
col2<-c(rep('R', each = 8))
col3<-c(rep('S', each = 8))
behaviour<-c(col1,col2,col3)
value <- runif(length(behaviour), min=0, max=0.0006)
species <- c(rep('B_theta', each = length(behaviour)))
test.data <- data.frame(behaviour, value, species)

d <- compare_means(value~behaviour, data = test.data,method = 't.test')
d %<>% mutate(y_pos = c(1.004,1.156763e-06,5.882128e-04),labels = ifelse(p<0.15,p.format,p.signif))
d

.y. group1  group2  p   p.adj   p.format    p.signif    method  y_pos   labels
value   E   R   0.4678791   0.76    0.47    ns          T-test  1.004000e+00    ns
value   E   S   0.1559682   0.47    0.16    ns          T-test  1.156763e-06    0.16
value   R   S   0.3794209   0.76    0.38    ns          T-test  5.882128e-04    ns


ggplot(data=subset(test.data, !is.na(value)), aes(x=behaviour,y=value)) + 
 geom_boxplot(aes(fill = behaviour), width=0.4,outlier.colour = "transparent")+
  geom_point(aes(fill = behaviour), size = 5, shape = 21, position = position_jitterdodge()) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("E" = '#3797a4', "R"= '#96bb7c',"S"= '#944e6c'))+
theme_classic()+
scale_y_log10() + annotation_logticks(sides = "l")+
geom_signif(data = as.data.frame(d), textsize=6, tip_length = 0.01, 
            aes(xmin=group1, xmax=group2, annotations=labels,y_position=y_pos),manual=TRUE)

Warning message:
"Ignoring unknown aesthetics: xmin, xmax, annotations, y_position"
```

This is what I currently get:
[image]

Desirable output:

[image]

Comment: where does the geom_siginif function come from? Could you add the necessary packages to your MRE?

Comment: Hi, I have added the libraries to the edit. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some problems to reproduce your example. Are you sure that the code you provided gave you this numbers? I really struggle to understand how a p-value of 0.16 can be smaller than 0.15 ???
Also, I am not familiar with the `geom_signif` function, all information I have is what i found in its help (`?geom_signif`)
Anyhow, with some minor changes I was able to create your desired plot:

```
library(magrittr) 
library(dplyr) 
library(ggpubr)

set.seed(20)
col1<-c(rep('E', each = 8))
col2<-c(rep('R', each = 8))
col3<-c(rep('S', each = 8))
behaviour<-c(col1,col2,col3)
value <- runif(length(behaviour), min=0, max=0.0006)
species <- c(rep('B_theta', each = length(behaviour)))
test.data <- data.frame(behaviour, value, species)

d <- compare_means(value~behaviour, data = test.data,method = 't.test')

# Here you manually specify the y-position of the significance bars
# The plot you got, was exactly what you specified here.
# But since we are using log10 scale for y Axis we should probably indicate
# The exponent i.e. -1, 0, 1 (as seen in your desired output plot)
# ALSO: I could not reproduce the significant result with your value for alpha of 0.15 -> had to use 0.25
#
# P.S. I will never use %<>% in my code. Ever! ;) (In my work, %<>% is an excellent footgun - it might save halve a second of typing,
# but you can only hope that nobody has ever to read the code again)
#
d <- d %>%  mutate(y_pos =  c(-1, 0, 1),labels = ifelse(p < 0.25, p.format, p.signif))

ggplot(data=subset(test.data, !is.na(value)), aes(x=behaviour,y=value)) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = behaviour), width=0.4,outlier.colour = "transparent")+
  geom_point(aes(fill = behaviour), size = 5, shape = 21, position = position_jitterdodge()) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("E" = '#3797a4', "R"= '#96bb7c',"S"= '#944e6c'))+
  theme_classic()+
  scale_y_log10() + annotation_logticks(sides = "l") +
  
  # The syntax you used did not correspond to the example I found in
  # ?geom_signif
  # If we just follow the example everything works and the warnings disappear
  #
  geom_signif(textsize=6, tip_length = 0.01, 
              xmin=d$group1, xmax=d$group2, annotations=d$labels, y_position=d$y_pos)
```

[image]